# Writing doesn't stop for files above ~2gb in C

Tags: c, file, io

I have some C code that is supposed to generate a password and save it to a file. I tried to enter a length that would be about 10 gb (absurdly big but I wanted to see how fast it could do it), and it didn't stop at 10 gb.

```
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(){
    int i = 0;
    char chars[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_-+={[]}\\|;:'\",<.>/?`~!@#$^&*()";
    long long size;
    char keypath[512];
    char password;
    printf("Where should the key be saved? ");
    fgets(keypath, sizeof(keypath), stdin);
    keypath[strcspn(keypath, "\n")] = 0;
    printf("How long should the key be? ");
    scanf("%lli",&size);
    getchar();
    srand((unsigned int)(time(NULL)));
    FILE* fptr = fopen(keypath,"a");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open file for writing\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int choice = rand() % strlen(chars);
        password = chars[choice];
        fprintf(fptr, "%c", chars[choice]);
    }
    fclose(fptr); 
    return 0;
}
```

It seems like when it goes somewhere over 1 gib (I assume 2 gib since that's the regular amount it goes to before using `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64`) it doesn't stop writing and instead keeps going seemingly indefinitely.

I am using Raspbian.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If int i is 32-bits, it will always be < 10G

Comment: The loop control is `int`. It will overflow around your "~ 2gb."

Comment: Tangental remark, rand() isn't suitable for cryptography. https://www.random.org/randomness/

Comment: @Nicholas Picklas, Save time.  enable all compiler warnings.  `int i = 0;` --> `long long i = 0;`.

Comment: Aside: why do you open the file in 'append' mode?

Comment: @EricJ. Yeah, I realized that. Honestly, I'm unsure how to implement a better system in such a low-level language.

Comment: @NicholasPicklas Implementing a pseudo random number generator is not different from "such a low-level language", than it would be in any other language. The difficult part is understanding the mathematics behind it. Usually if you don't know the math, as in my case, you just take [the implementation someone else did](https://github.com/ESultanik/mtwister).

Comment: @NicholasPicklas Or this one: http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/m-mat/MT/SFMT/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is good that you made the variable `size` to be of the type `long long`, so that it is guaranteed to be able to represent a file size of 10 GB.

However, you forgot to do the same with the variable `i`. Instead, you gave `i` the data type `int`.

Due to this, the loop

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
    int choice = rand() % strlen(chars);
    password = chars[choice];
    fprintf(fptr, "%c", chars[choice]);
}
```

will invoke undefined behavior due to signed integer overflow, unless you happen to be on a platform on which `int` is able to represent a file size of 10 GB. On most common PC platforms, [`INT_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) (which is the maximum value an `int` can represent) has a value of `2147483647`. On those platforms, an `int` is unable to represent the value `10000000000`.